# Setting a new property on an object in an Angular directive for use in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that is populating a `div`.  It takes in a object, does some logic to figure out a variable, inserts the variable into the template and returns the template to the `div`.

How can I set a new property on the object and pass it back to the controller for use?

For example:
HTML:

```
<div node-icon node="node"></div>
```

Object going in

```
{ name: 'Apple',
  count: 5,
  price: '$5'
}
```

Directive Logic

```
.directive('nodeName', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {node: '='},
    template: '<span ng-bind-html="color"></span>',

    link: function ($scope) {
      if(node.name === 'Apple') {
        $scope.color = 'red';
      }
    }
  };
}])
```

I want to pass the object back to the controller looking like this

```
{ name: 'Apple',
  count: 5,
  price: '$5',
  color: 'red'
}
```

Comment: You should just set it on the `node` right? i.e `$scope.node.color = 'red';` You will see it in your controller as well. You don't have to pass data around that is the benefit of 2 way binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending the object in with  scope: {node: '='}, 
just use scope.node and append the property (it's javascript, it will work).

The link function declaration is wrong , though.

```
link: function link(scope, element, attrs) { {
  if(scope.node.name === 'Apple') {
    scope.node.color = 'red';
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The `scope: {node: '='}` means there is a two-way binding between the variable of the host scope (the scope in which the directive is used) that is passed in the `node` attribute, and the `node` variable in the directive's own scope. Therefore in the `link` function, you can read and write `scope.node` and the changes will be reflected in the host scope.

```
link: function (scope) {
    if(scope.node.name === 'Apple') {
        scope.node.color = 'red';
    }
}
```